# JPA Fetch Join Filter on List/Set

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, jpql

I'm having problem on JPA (Hibernate) Fetch Join :

Here is my JPQL query

`SELECT n FROM News n LEFT JOIN FETCH n.profiles AS pr WHERE pr.id=?1`

But it's not working. How can I make a query that filters on the list that is being fetched ?

Comment: Could you post the `News` class code?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816417/how-to-properly-express-jpql-join-fetch-with-where-clause-as-jpa-2-criteriaq; short summary:

- JPA spec does not allow JOIN FETCH with alias

- hibernate does not complain, if using JOIN FETCH with alias

- you can easily shoot yourself in the foot, using JOIN FETCH with alias

Answer (score 8):

According to the specification, what you're trying to do is not allowed (at least not by JPA). From the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 4.4.5.3 Fetch Joins
>
> A FETCH JOIN enables the fetching of
>   an association as a side effect of the
>   execution of a query. A FETCH JOIN is
>   specified over an entity and its
>   related entities.
>
> The syntax for a fetch join is
>
> ```
> fetch_join ::= [ LEFT [OUTER] | INNER ] JOIN FETCH join_association_path_expression
> ```
>
> The association referenced by the
>   right side of the FETCH JOIN clause
>   must be an association that belongs to
>   an entity that is returned as a result
>   of the query. **It is not permitted to
>   specify an identification variable for
>   the entities referenced by the right
>   side of the FETCH JOIN clause, and
>   hence references to the implicitly
>   fetched entities cannot appear
>   elsewhere in the query.**

So the following should work:

```
SELECT n FROM News n LEFT JOIN n.profiles p WHERE p.id = ?1
```

But you can't use a FETCH JOIN here.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
SELECT n FROM News n LEFT JOIN FETCH n.profiles AS pr WITH (pr.id=?1)
```