# How to write an SQL SELECT in JPA with 3 JOINs?

Tags: sql, jpa, ejb, entity, jpql

I have entities:

```
@Entity(name = "sent_message")
public class SentMessage extends AbstractEntity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private TargetGroup targetGroup;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Customer customer;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private MessageTemplate template;
    private Date sentDate;
    getter.setter...
}

@Entity(name = "target_group")
public class TargetGroup extends AbstractEntity {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
    getter.setter...
}

@Entity(name = "customer")
public class Customer extends AbstractEntity {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String mobile;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="customers", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TargetGroup> targetGroups = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<SentMessage> sentMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    getter.setter...
}

@Entity(name = "message_template")
public class MessageTemplate extends AbstractEntity {
    private String subject;
    private String text;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "template", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<SentMessage> sentMessages;
    getter.setter...
}
```

I want the TargetGroup, Customer, MessageTemplate to be the result of the query. My SELECT:

```
SELECT msg FROM SentMessage msg JOIN msg.targetGroup tg, msg.customer cust, msg.template temp WHERE ....
```

Is that correct, or how should I write it? I want all the parameters from all entities.
Thank you!

**EDIT**: I want to search by the name of the TargetGroup, the name of the Customer, and others, how should I write it in the WHERE??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to list the results you want in the `select` clause of the query:

```
SELECT msg.targetGroup, msg.customer, msg.template FROM SentMessage msg
```

You will get an `Object[]` containing the data.

If you are experiencing problems due to lazy fetching, you can add fetch joins to retrieve the relating entities:

```
SELECT msg.targetGroup, msg.customer, msg.template FROM SentMessage msg join fetch msg.targetGroup tg join fetch  msg.customer cust join fetch msg.template temp
```

**EDIT** Your comment suggests that you also need the 'parent' message in your results. In this case, it does not make sense to create a projection query (listing all the attributes in the select clause). Just fetch the parent message and call the regular getters to access the `Customer`, `TargetGroup` and other associations. Use fetch joins if problems with lazy fetching arise.

```
SELECT msg FROM SentMessage msg
```

or

```
SELECT msg FROM SentMessage msg join fetch msg.targetGroup tg join fetch  msg.customer cust join fetch msg.template temp
```

**EDIT 2** For adding constraints to your query, you can add regular `where` clauses referencing any id variable:

```
... join fetch  msg.customer cust where cust.name = :cust_name...
```

However the behaviour of the fetch join together with where clauses is a bit unexpected - the fetch is restricted as well by the `where` clause. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816417/how-to-properly-express-jpql-join-fetch-with-where-clause-as-jpa-2-criteriaq/5819631) for reference

Comment: I list the 3 results (msg.targetGroup, msg.customer, msg.template), will I get the paramters from the SentMessage table too? Or should I write it like: `SELECT msg, msg.targetGroup, msg.customer, msg.template FROM SentMessage msg `

Comment: and how to search in the WHERE place if I want to check a parameter from the Customer table? Maybe I want to search for the Customer's name, how should I write it in the WHERE?

Comment: @victorio I hope I understood you correctly. Please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @victorio - please dont just pile up follow up questions in comments. Check if your original request has been resolved and return with some feedback. Once the initial issue is solved, open a new thread for further questions.

Comment: Almost! But what if I want to search for the customer's name in the WHERE, and search for the name of the TargetGroup (also in the WHERE)??

Comment: @victorio I hope the new edit will clarify ht eissue

Comment: perfect, thank you! :) maybe you could answer my new question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517502/why-isnt-my-entity-table-mapped-in-jpa-hibernate