# Hibernate, How can I detach and/or get data only on demand?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity setup like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APP", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "APP_KEY"))
public class Application implements java.io.Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "application_Id", referencedColumnName = "application_Id")
    private Set<Document> documents = new HashSet<Document>(0);
}
```

Now, in some situations I don't want the list of documents to be returned.  However when I serialize this object  the "getDocuments()" method will be called.

There will not be an active transaction at this time, so I don't want one of those "no session" errors. I just want to ignore it and have the getDocuments() method return empty, not throw an exception and not try to fetch more data.

Comment: I would go for setting empty Set manually after detachment but before serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the FetchGroup capability ref:

Take a look at the jpql fetch join's...

```
Select e from Employee e join fetch e.phones p where p.areaCode = '613'
```

This was covered for a similar question here: [How to properly express JPQL "join fetch" with "where" clause as JPA 2 CriteriaQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816417/how-to-properly-express-jpql-join-fetch-with-where-clause-as-jpa-2-criteriaq)

Comment: I don't think this is what Triton Man is asking for. He doesn't want to fetch but don't want `LazyInitializationException` either.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your serialization setup, however:

- If you are using Jackson, you can use this : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate which works quite nicely.
- If you have a manual serialization setup, you should probably not be calling methods directly, without prior knowledge of their initialization status. What you could do is use something like Hibernate.isInitialized(*object.Method*)
  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#isInitialized-java.lang.Object-