# Querying hierarchical data with JPQL / HQL

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, hql, jpql

We are trying to implement a simple model of hierarchical data, which is as follows.

```
public class Team {
    /* ... */

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "team")
    protected List<Member> members;
}

public class Member {
    /* ... */

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected Team team;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "member")
    protected List<Assignment> assignments;
}

public class Assigment {
    /* ... */

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected Member member;
}
```

The idea behind the mapping is quite straightforward - a team is composed of members, who are in turn assigned some duties.

Problem: creating a query which will return the hierarchy of team->member->assignment with conditions imposed on assignments (e.g. deadline in < 1 week).

Solutions so far:

1. Querying for all Team entities and iterating over two-level collections in a transaction, filtering out those assignments, which do not fall into time range.
   Pros: simple. Cons: possible large overhead.
2. Following query:

   ```
   SELECT t FROM Team t
     left join fetch t.members m
     left join fetch m.assignments
   ```

   Unfortunately, the query fails even without the any condition for assigment filtering, throwing:

   ```
   org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags
   ```

I don't understand why it does not allow simultaneous fetching on two relations, as a similar example is shown in Hibernate docs:

```
from Cat as cat
  inner join fetch cat.mate
  left join fetch cat.kittens child
  left join fetch child.kittens
```

Questions:

1. Is it possible to fetch the whole tree-like collection with filtered leaf-level (assignments) with a single SQL statement? If not, what could be improved in the proposed solution?
2. Why the double fetch does not work properly?

Additional info: we're using Hibernate 4.3.5.FINAL & PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

The double fetch means a Cartesian Product, So if you have 100 teams with 100 members and 100 assignments you will get 100 x 100 X 100 = 1,000,000 results.

The best way of fetching is from the bottom-up.

```
SELECT a FROM Assigment a
  inner join fetch a.member m
  inner join fetch m.team t
```

and reconstruct the tree from the bottom-up. You can use the [`EntityGraphBuilder`](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-multi-level-fetching/) to map it in Java.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to fetch the whole tree-like collection with filtered
>   leaf-level (assignments) with a single SQL statement? If not, what
>   could be improved in the proposed solution?

Yes, it's possible. But, you need to change your mapping to use `Set` instead of `List`.

> Why the double fetch does not work properly?

When you try to fetch multiple collections you cannot have two or more `List` in the same query.

So, change the assignments or members from `List` to `Set`.

To filter the assigments you [cannot do that in a fetched clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816417/how-to-properly-express-jpql-join-fetch-with-where-clause-as-jpa-2-criteriaq). If you want to fetch all collections and do a filter in assigment, your query could be:

```
SELECT t FROM Team t
  join fetch t.members m -- only for fetch
  join fetch m.assignments -- only for fetch
  join t.members member -- new join to do the where
  join member.assigments assigment -- new join to do the where
  where assigment.anyAttribute = someValue -- filter assigment
```

But, as @Vlad said, the cartesian product can be huge with this solution and bring a lot of unecessary information in the SQL result.