# The Parent doensn't retrieve the childs hibertnate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jpa

I have a Controller from rest service that I call a Hibernate method to get the result, but I really don't know why the children components didn't come. When I call this method using Junit, It works.
This is the Code:

```
{

@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6131311050358241535L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private String description;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
}


{

@Entity
public class Image implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2128787860415180858L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;

    private ImageType type;
}
{

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public List<Product> findAllWithParentProductsAndImage() {
String hpql = "select distinct p from Product p left join fetch p.images";
List<Product> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(hpql, 
        Product.class).getResultList();
return resultList;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you aren't loading the children laziily?

Comment: Wrap the @Transaction(readOnly=true) in the service should allow the lazy loading child to be accessed lazily.

Answer (score 1):

By default `@OneToMany` will load lazily. 
You should use `@OneToMany(  mappedBy = "product", fetch=FetchType.Eager )` to do Eager fetch

Comment: This will always fetch children even if you only want the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch=FetchType.Eager)
```

However this has a downside. You will always be fetching children even if you only want the **Parent** and its few properties.

Use `JOIN FETCH` within your `@Query` if you are using JpaRepositories.

Check out the following related questions

- [How to properly express JPQL "join fetch" with "where" clause as JPA 2 CriteriaQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5816417/3094731)
- http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from#LEFT_OUTER_INNER_JOIN_FETCH_
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29667050/3094731