# JPA Criteria API - Accessing fields of One-to-Many collection association

Tags: jpa, left-join, jpql, eager-loading, criteria-api

How could I write the following JPQL query using Criteria API?

```
" select a from A a left join fetch a.bs b where b.i like 'X%' "
```

A-to-B is a One-To-Many relationship where A and B is like following:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<B>();   

    //...
}

@Entity
public class B {

    private String i;
    
    //...
}
```

I tried the foolowing:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();           
CriteriaQuery<A> cq = cb.createQuery( A.class );
Root<A> aRoot = cq.from( A.class );
Fetch<A, B> bs = aRoot.fetch(A_.bs, JoinType.LEFT);
cq.where(cb.like(what_do_i_do_here, "X%"));
cq.select(aRoot);
```

I need to get all those `A`s along with its associated `B`s where the `i` value of the associated `B`s start with an `"X"`.

**EDIT**:

If I try the method given at [How to properly express JPQL "join fetch" with "where" clause as JPA 2 CriteriaQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816417/how-to-properly-express-jpql-join-fetch-with-where-clause-as-jpa-2-criteriaq) I **incorrectly** get 2 `A`s in result while I should get just 1 `A` whose associated B_.i has the value that starts with "X".

I got the issue resolved using the following code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();           
CriteriaQuery<A> cq = builder.createQuery( A.class );
Root<A> root = cq.from( A.class );
Join<A, B> bs = (Join<A, B>) root.fetch(Guide_.students, JoinType.LEFT);
cq.where(builder.like(bs.get(B_.i), builder.parameter(String.class, "i")));
cq.select(root);
            
TypedQuery<A> query = em.createQuery(criteria).setParameter("i", "X%");         
List<A> as= query.getResultList();          
for (A a: as) {
  System.out.println(a);
}
```

Comment: have you look at this ? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html#gjiuv

Comment: the class finished in underscore is what is known as a metamodel.

It is used to access the properties of an entity when doing joins (or fetch) as well as to compare or work with them.

In eclipse they are generated automatically if you secondary click on the project / properties / JPA and in the "Canonical Metamodel 2.0" section you select the directory where you want them to be generated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly express JPQL "join fetch" with "where" clause as JPA 2 CriteriaQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816417/how-to-properly-express-jpql-join-fetch-with-where-clause-as-jpa-2-criteriaq)

Comment: @crizzis Thanks crizzis, it helped. I got it working with the following. There should be a better way to get it done though.    `CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();           
   CriteriaQuery<A> cq = cb.createQuery( A.class );
   Root<A> aRoot = cq.from( A.class );
   Join<A, B> bs = (Join<A, B>) aRoot.fetch(A_.bs, JoinType.LEFT);
   cq.where(cb.like(bs.get(B_.i), builder.parameter(String.class, "i")));
   cq.select(aRoot);   
   TypedQuery<A> query = em.createQuery(cq).setParameter("i", "X%");`

Comment: @gaetanTEMATE Thanks gaten. It helped but I couldn't help me with the solution of the given issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Join<ParentTable,ChildTable> to get and filter child entities. Try below code

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();           
CriteriaQuery<A> cq = cb.createQuery( A.class );
Root<A> aRoot = cq.from( A.class );
Join<A, B> bs = root.join(A_.B);
cq.where(cb.like(bs.get(B_.i), "X%"));
cq.select(aRoot);
```

Note - I didn't get a chance to test this code. You can refer to working code which I implemented for similar problem here https://github.com/bsridharpatnaik/SpecificationTest

Edit - Providing Detailed Answer

I have made new push to the repo. Please take latest pull.

I created exact same example that you mentioned.

Entity classes

```
public class A 
{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long aid;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<B>();
// get & set
}

public class B 
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long bid;
    
    String i;
//get & set
}
```

Now, as per your query, you want to filter all records from class A where corresponding B.i starts with x.

Below is service class. to make it easy to understand, I wrote criteroa query logic in separate class

```
@Service
public class Service1 
{
    @Autowired
    aRepo repo;
    
    @Autowired
    ModelSpecification modelSpecification;

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;
    public List<?> getResults() throws ParseException 
    {
        //ModelSpecification modelSpecification = new ModelSpecification();
        CriteriaQuery<A> query = modelSpecification.getSpecQuery();
        TypedQuery<A> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
        List<A> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

Below is the criteria query logic

```
@Component
public class ModelSpecification 
{
    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;
    
    public CriteriaQuery<A> getSpecQuery() throws ParseException
    {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<A> query = builder.createQuery(A.class);
        Root<A> root = query.from(A.class);
        Join<A,B>   ab = root.join(A_.BS);
        query.where(builder.like(ab.get(B_.I),"x"+"%"));
        return query;
    }
}
```

I am filtering all A records where B_.I starts with x.

Output
Class A has below entries for aid - 1,2
Class B has below entries for
[image: data for B]

join table a_bs has below entries
[image: data for a_bs]

Now, if I hit API, I should get only A record with aid =1 as only it is associated with B.i starting with x.

[image: postman output]

Comment: Thanks Sridhar. The given code does not work. The link mentioned does not help either. I do not know where to look for the relevant code in the given link.

Comment: @skip I modified the code to match with exact example as mentioned by you. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks Sridhar, but in your query there is no fetching. I needed a `left join fetch` which would eagerly load the `B`s data as well along with `A`s data where B_.i starts with an 'X". I have edited my question that shows how I got the issue resolved.

Comment: @skip Welcome. happy to hear that the problem got resolved. Please add it here as an answer here so that it can help others.