# JPA WHERE clause on many-to-many entity

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

I have two table, Book and Genre. Each book may have many genre, and the many-to-many table only contain the Book ID and Genre ID.
I want to create a filter which would filter books by it's genre(s).

```
  @JoinTable(name = "bookGenre", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "bookId", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "genreId", referencedColumnName = "id")})
  @ManyToMany
  private Collection<Genre> genreCollection;
```

Genre Class:

```
  @Id
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;
  @Size(max = 255)
  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
  @Column(name = "status")
  private Integer status;
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "genreCollection")
  private Collection<Book> bookCollection;
```

This is the query that I'm trying to do on JPA:

```
SELECT b.title FROM book b
JOIN bookGenre bg on bg.bookId = b.id
JOIN genre g on bg.genreId = g.id
WHERE g.id = 1
--Filter books that have genre with id 1
```

I've tried the following on JPA:
`SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.genreCollection.id = 1`

But it gave me the following error:
"The state field path 'b.genreCollection.id' cannot be resolved to a valid type."

EDIT:
I found out that i can use native sql query with built in result set mapping to Book POJO `EntityManager.createNativeQuery(query, Book.class)`. So i just use that and string together my query with StringJoiner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly express JPQL "join fetch" with "where" clause as JPA 2 CriteriaQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816417/how-to-properly-express-jpql-join-fetch-with-where-clause-as-jpa-2-criteriaq)

Comment: I tried using INNER JOIN and yes it worked but now the list of books is repeating. Just like selecting from detail table or in my case bookGenre table.

Answer (score 0):

I think your JPA Query should be

```
SELECT b FROM Book b INNER JOIN b.genreCollection g WHERE g.id = 1
```

Comment: It works but now the list of books is repeating, just like selecting from the detail table

Comment: Check the generated SQL query, is being correctly generated?