# Query using specifications gives error when ordering on joined column that is not in SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I get following error when doing a rather complicated query: `for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

In the query I need to find all distinct `Requests` that have an `ExploitationSite` that contains a search term in their dutch or french name. The result has to be ordered by the `Activity`'s dutch name and limited to the first 10 for pagination.

To do this query I use the [`Page <T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-) method of JpaSpecificationExecutor.

This will result in a SELECT DISTINCT query which has to be ORDERed BY a property that is not in SELECT. (details below)

I tried to fetch the activities eagerly in the hope it would place those differently in the SELECT. I did my best trying to get the DISTINCT in a subquery and then have the ORDER BY + LIMIT around that, but I did not succeed in that.

Has someone an idea how I can get this query to work?

The (simplified) `Request` entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "request_requests")
@History("Request")
public class Request extends EqualByStateObject {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Embedded
    private RequestNumber requestNumber;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_request")
    private List<ExploitationSite> exploitationSites = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(unique = true, name = "fk_activity")
    private Activity activity;

    ...
}
```

The Specification (I have to use distinct here because since a `Request` contains a List of `ExploitationSites` it was possible I got the same request multiple times back if multiple `ExploitationSites` contained the search term)

```java
public class ExploitationSiteSpecification extends EqualByStateObject implements Specification<Request> {
    private final String exploitationSiteName;

    protected ExploitationSiteSpecification(String exploitationSiteName) {
        this.exploitationSiteName = exploitationSiteName;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Request> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        query.distinct(true);
        ListJoin<Object, Object> exploitationSites = root.joinList("exploitationSites");
        return criteriaBuilder.or(
                criteriaBuilder.like(
                        criteriaBuilder.lower(exploitationSites.get("name").get("dutchName")), "%" + exploitationSiteName.toLowerCase() + "%"),
                criteriaBuilder.like(
                        criteriaBuilder.lower(exploitationSites.get("name").get("frenchName")), "%" + exploitationSiteName.toLowerCase() + "%")
        );
    }
}
```

The Pageable

```java
public Pageable getPageable() {
    Sort sort = Sort.by(Sort.Order.asc("activity.name.dutchName"));

    PageRequest.of(0, 10, sort);
}
```

This results in a generated query like this one

```sql
select distinct request0_.id as id1_23_, 
    request0_.fk_activity as fk_acti15_23_,
    request0_.request_number as request12_23_

from request_requests request0_ 
    inner join request_exploitation_sites exploitati1_ on request0_.id=exploitati1_.fk_request 
    left outer join request_activity activity2_ on request0_.fk_activity=activity2_.id

where lower(exploitati1_.dutch_name) like $1 
        or lower(exploitati1_.french_name) like $2

order by activity2_.dutch_name asc limit $3
```

which then gives the `for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list` error

Comment: You need to select `dutch_name` also to order by that column

Comment: I wish it was as easy as that, but it's difficult to change the query directly since it is automatically generated.

Comment: You can multiselect the column for  distinct `query.multiselect(exploitationSites.get("id"),exploitationSites.get("name").get("dutchName")).distinct(true);`

Comment: It looked promising, but it unfortunately did not change the generated query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you put the `distinct` because the join with `exploitationSites` would return multiple rows, the following two options would work without using `distinct`.

1. right after the `join` you could do an additional `fetch`

```java
ListJoin<Object, Object> exploitationSites = root.joinList("exploitationSites");
root.fetch("exploitationSites")
```

this would result in hibernate to create an additional join of `ExploitationSites` as well as selecting additional columns

```
select request0_.id as id1_23_, 
    request0_.fk_activity as fk_acti15_23_,
    request0_.request_number as request12_23_,
    exploitati3_.id as exploitati3_id,
    exploitati3_.name as exploitati3_name,
    ...

from request_requests request0_ 
    inner join request_exploitation_sites exploitati1_ on request0_.id=exploitati1_.fk_request 
    left outer join request_activity activity2_ on request0_.fk_activity=activity2_.id
    inner join request_exploitation_sites exploitati3_ on request0_.id=exploitati3_.fk_request 

where lower(exploitati1_.dutch_name) like $1 
        or lower(exploitati1_.french_name) like $2

order by activity2_.dutch_name asc limit $3
```

2. use `fetch` in the first place and cast it to `Join`

```
Join<Object, Object> exploitationSites = (Join<Object, Object>) root.fetch("exploitationSites");
```

By casting the `Fetch` to a `Join` you can still use `where` clauses.

Note that this will also select additional columns, but won't do an additional `join` in the resulting query.

---

In both cases the `fetch` will result in a `join fetch` which hibernate internally will remove duplicates from the parent entity (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51177569)